# Apache POI delete CellStyle from workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using apache POI ... I used workbook.CreateCellStyle(), if after a while I needed to delete the CellStyle created ... How do I remove it from the workbook? I can see it still remains even if it is unused.

What I need is something like workbook.deleteCellStyle(cellStyle.getIndex());

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the source the following method deletes unused CellStyles:

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFOptimiser.optimiseCellStyles(HSSFWorkbook)
```

Comment: It does look like it should do the job... but running it doesn't really do anything! I will try to debug it again later.

Answer (score 4):

As of [r1391891](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1391891), HSSFOptimiser will also remove un-used styles, in addition to removing duplicate cell styles.

So, grab yourself a recent nightly build / svn checkout build (or just wait for the 3.9-beta1 release in a month or so!), and then do something like:

```
NPOIFSFileSystem poifs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("/path/to/excel/file.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(poifs.getRoot());
HSSFOptimiser.optimiseCellStyles(wb);

FileOutputStream fout = new FileoutputStream("optimised.xls");
wb.write(fout);
fout.close()
```

After that, `optimsed.xls` will contain no duplicated cell styles, and no un-used cell styles. (You could easily put the optimise step at the end of creating the file, if it's not already existing)

Note - the HSSFOptimiser approach will only work for .xls files, not for XSSF .xlsx ones. It should be possible to generalise the approach with not too much work, but for now it's HSSF only....

Comment: This is the useful and supercharged version of my (too-general) answer -- +1.

Comment: This approach solves only half of the problem leaving me with OOXML format(*.xlsx files) untouched. On the other hand, it shouldn't be that hard to convert xlsx -> xls -> xlsx. I should try it and see what's the performance.

Comment: @Gagravarr is there any way to do this for Xlsx...??

Comment: @PrasannaKumar Nope, still needs someone to volunteer to write a XSSF version based on the HSSF one

Comment: @Gagravarr what about date data type...? Everytime we need to take new cell style and clone it with EXISTING cell style(reason to create new always) in the referred file.....it exceeds always....is there any way to prevent that

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct method in the current source code:

This is how the style is created:

```
public HSSFCellStyle createCellStyle()
{
    ...
    ExtendedFormatRecord xfr = workbook.createCellXF();
    short index = (short) (getNumCellStyles() - 1);
    HSSFCellStyle style = new HSSFCellStyle(index, xfr, this);
    return style;
}
```

with

```
public short getNumCellStyles()
{
    return (short) workbook.getNumExFormats();
}
```

and (in InternalWorkbook)

```
public int getNumExFormats() {
    ...
    return numxfs;
}
```

and with the workbook.createCellXF() resolving to:

```
public ExtendedFormatRecord createCellXF() {
    ExtendedFormatRecord xf = createExtendedFormat();

    records.add(records.getXfpos()+1, xf);
    records.setXfpos( records.getXfpos() + 1 );
    numxfs++;
    return xf;
}
```

So what is possible from the HSSFWorkbook, is to call:

```
InternalWorkbook getWorkbook() {
    return workbook;
}
```

and then on the InternalWorkbook object:

```
public ExtendedFormatRecord getExFormatAt(int index) {
    int xfptr = records.getXfpos() - (numxfs - 1);

    xfptr += index;
    ExtendedFormatRecord retval =
    ( ExtendedFormatRecord ) records.get(xfptr);

    return retval;
}

public void removeExFormatRecord(ExtendedFormatRecord rec) {
    records.remove(rec); // this updates XfPos for us
    numxfs--;
}
```

So to make it short, from the top workbook, something like this:

```
 InternalWorkbook w = workbook.getWorkbook();
 ExtendedFormatRecord record = w.getExFormatAt(index);
 w.removeExFormatRecord(record);
```

This is all very horrible :)

Comment: I think that might lead me to something. I just took a quick look at the ExtendedFormatRecord and it seems to me that both styles and cells are ExtendedFormatRecords. If I figure out the correct number of style in this index I believe I might be able to remove it. However, I am afraid that all of the references from cells to (removed) style will get corrupted...

Comment: You'll need to fix up references too, otherwise things will break when you shuffle the order of the XFs around with the removal. Take a look at HSSFOptimiser to see what's required to be done!

Comment: Although this is not the full answer to my question, this simple copy past of poi source code pointed me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Turned out it's the same index number for getExFormatAt() as for getCellStyleAt().

Answer (score 1):

Getting the cell and setting NOTHING to style may work :

```
HSSFRow hr= workBook.getSheet("SheetName").getRow(rowIndex);
HSSFCell hc=hr.getCell(cellIndex);
hc.setCellStyle(null);
```

Please try this may this will work for you.

Comment: The style still will be stored in the file. After searching for few days, I claim there is no straightforward way to delete style from the workbook using Apache POI.

Answer (score 1):

**You could work around the problem by copying data with any required cellstyles to a newly-created workbook.** The cellstyle "survival" behind the scenes appears to be buggy, or not well thought-out.

Comment: This isn't a good advice. What if the book has 3 or more heavy data and OP just needs to delete a single cell?

Comment: What´s "3 or more heavy data"? And: He is not deleting cells, he wants to get rid of unreferenced cellstyles. A workaround is a workaround, and this is one, and not a solution, so: so what. If you have one, let us know.

Comment: The survival of cellstyle, while copying the values of the cells, is none. The styles will be all left behind. That means I will need to create new styles in the new workbook. The cellstyle manager could help me with this task. However I am worried about the performance.

@Luiggi: You are right. There will be cases where none of the styles will be deleted, but I still have to make sure the are no unused/duplicated.