# Modifying XSSFWorkbook stylesheet to remove duplicate CellStyleXfs

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

After trouble viewing certain xlsx files on the iPad, I tracked the problem to the styles.xml file in the xlsx archive being too large. I was able to view a file after manually removing duplicate entries and letting excel repair the file, but to solve the case for other files I would rather have a programmatic solution using POI, unfortunately I have been running into problems when trying to save a workbook after I've modified the stylesheet.

I tried to copy the format of optimiseCellStyles(HSSFWorkbook workbook) for an HSSFWorkbook but the internals are different and the offending styles are only of a particular type.
After checking a number of XSSFWorkbook functions I found that

```
XSSFWorkbook wb; // with proper initialization
wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().getCellStyleXfs();
```

was returning approximately 40,000 entries, the bulk of which were

```
<main:xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0"/>
```

So I tried to identify the location of duplicates in the book and remove them via a call to

```
XSSFWorkbook wb; // with proper initialization
wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().getCellStyleXfs().removeXf(i);
```

but after removing styles when trying to save the file StylesTable.java throws an error about org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException And I have attempted a number of different avenues and received similar errors.

Looking at the code in StylesTable.java it appears that class keeps a separate copy of the stylesheet than CTStylesheet and the difference in size after modifying one is causing the problem, but I imagine I am misunderstanding how to properly track these records, particularly because

```
XSSFCell cell; //with proper initialization
cell.getCellStyle().getStyleXf().getXfId();
```

is always returning a number between 1 and 5 despite the thousands of entries in the xml file.

Is there a more standard way of cleaning up this section of the workbook that I am missing?

Am I horribly misunderstanding the workbook internals or POI functions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the latest, did you try upgrading?

Comment: I am currently using poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar which is currently the latest stable version. As I mentioned Ive seen this for HSSFWorkbook objects, and I have seen lots of examples of adding and setting styles but none for removing and cleaning up styles in an XSSFWorkbook. So I hope this is possible, but I don't believe I am the first person trying this. This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168896/apache-poi-delete-cellstyle-from-workbook mentioned converting xlsx files to xls and using the hssfoptimizer but I think the conversion down is not an acceptable solution for us.

Comment: You're going to have to monkey with the `xfs` list in StylesTable if you want to do this + have it work. May be best to open an enhancement entry in the POI Bugzilla, then work to produce a XSSF Styles Optimiser which probably includes a handful of protected new styles methods to help