# POI Excel Merging Causing "Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)"

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

I have merged two excel files using the code specied here

http://www.coderanch.com/t/614715/Web-Services/java/merge-excel-files

this the block applying the styles for my merging cells

```
 if (styleMap != null)
{
  if (oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook())
  {
    newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
  }
  else
  {
    int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
    XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
    if (newCellStyle == null)
    {
      newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
      newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
      styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
    }
    newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
  }
}
```

It all working as expected and going well in generating my XSSFWorkbook.

Problem starting when I try to open it:

I see below error

[image][image]

and my error report contains below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error072840_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Errors were detected in file 'XYZ.xlsx'</summary>
    <repairedRecords summary="Following is a list of repairs:">
        <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)</repairedRecord>
    </repairedRecords>
</recoveryLog>
```

After all these my sheet opens up fine but without styles. I know there is a limitation on number of styles to be created and have counted the styles being created and I hardly see 4 created. I even know that this issue is with too many styles.

Unfortunately, POI has support to optimise only HSSFWorkbook ([Apache POI delete CellStyle from workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168896/apache-poi-delete-cellstyle-from-workbook))

Any help in how to mitigate with this issue will be great.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the most recent release? (3.11 beta 2 as of writing)

Comment: Yes, I tried using 3.11 beta 2 and still I see the same problem. Earlier I was on 3.9 though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after debugging bit of POI code and how styles are being applied and so.

Doing below solved the problem

```
newCellStyle.getCoreXf().unsetBorderId();
      newCellStyle.getCoreXf().unsetFillId();
```

Comment: Let me ask you, what did you have previous to these updated code?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
You should to minimize instances of styles and fonts because each instance is placed into `xl/styles.xml`

Make styles and fonts only once for one book.

Comment: I don't have multiple styles.. I just had one per book. Above said solution works well.

Comment: Although Shivs issue is not related to a total number of style created on a workbook, but this can be caused by it and for me, it was exactly what was happening, the maximum cap for styles you can create is around 50k to 60k in a workbook.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using the Python library xlxswriter with Pandas.  After I stopped trying to use Pandas' date_format specification, I stopped getting the error.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('somefile.xlsx')
grp = data.groupby('Property Manager')

for i, (pm, g) in enumerate(grp):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(p + f.format(pm[:30]), engine='xlsxwriter') #,date_format='%m/%d/%Y')
    g[cols].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary', index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Comment: I would say that it isn't the same issue, just similar symptoms (which are very common for a wide range of Excel errors). In the pandas example it is probably caused by the date format, `'%m/%d/%Y'`, which isn't valid in Excel. Try something like `'mm/dd/yy'` instead.