# Using Apache POI to get Border & Fill Styles for new cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Following the post made @ [POI Excel Merging Causing "Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880954)

I have two excel files which are opening fine with styles and colors (In microsoft office 2010).

Iam merging both of those excel files using the code posted in the thread above.

The problem is with the styles (I created styles as below):

```
newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
      newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCellStyle);
      styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
```

which has caused the styles problem "**Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)**"

after a fair amount of research what I learnt is the border and fill is causing the problem. Un setting these parameters has solved the problem. But as it states border and fill went missing.

Can some one throws idea around how to get the border and fill style from a cell and apply to a new cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the post  at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55800

As we are having trouble with border and fill

adding below piece of code worked like Charm

```
newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
          newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCellStyle);
          //          newCellStyle.getCoreXf().unsetBorderId();
          //          newCellStyle.getCoreXf().unsetFillId();
          StylesTable newStylesSource = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getStylesSource();
          StylesTable oldStylesSource = oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getStylesSource();
          for (XSSFCellFill fill : oldStylesSource.getFills())
          {
            XSSFCellFill fillNew = new XSSFCellFill(fill.getCTFill());
            newStylesSource.putFill(fillNew);
          }
          for (XSSFCellBorder border : oldStylesSource.getBorders())
          {
            XSSFCellBorder borderNew = new XSSFCellBorder(border.getCTBorder());
            newStylesSource.putBorder(borderNew);
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [bug in Apache POI, #55800](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55800).  The border ID and fill ID used in the "CoreXf" object aren't copied, causing the issue.

According to [Comment 5 on that bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55800#c5), it is possible to work around it by copying the fill and border attributes manually yourself.

> The reason is it won't copy the XSSFCellFill and XSSFCellBorder. This also gives problem with borders. I have added a method in org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable which will help in creating a copy of workbook.
>
> ```
> public void copyTo(StylesTable stylesTable){
>   stylesTable.numberFormats.clear();
>   stylesTable.fonts.clear();
>   stylesTable.fills.clear();
>   stylesTable.borders.clear();
>   stylesTable.styleXfs.clear();
>   stylesTable.xfs.clear();
>   stylesTable.dxfs.clear();
>   
>   for(String str : numberFormats.values())
>       stylesTable.putNumberFormat(str);
>   
>   for(XSSFFont font : fonts){
>       XSSFFont fontNew = new XSSFFont(font.getCTFont());
>       fontNew.registerTo(stylesTable);
>   }
>   for(XSSFCellFill fill : fills){
>       XSSFCellFill fillNew = new XSSFCellFill(fill.getCTFill());
>       stylesTable.putFill(fillNew);
>   }
>   for(XSSFCellBorder border : borders){
>       XSSFCellBorder borderNew = new XSSFCellBorder(border.getCTBorder());
>       stylesTable.putBorder(borderNew);
>   }
>   for(CTXf ctxf : styleXfs){
>       CTXf ctxfNew = (CTXf)ctxf.copy();
>       stylesTable.putCellStyleXf(ctxfNew);
>   }
>   for(CTXf ctxf : xfs){
>       CTXf ctxfNew = (CTXf)ctxf.copy();
>       stylesTable.putCellXf(ctxfNew);
>   }
>   for(CTDxf dxf : dxfs){
>       CTDxf dxfNew = (CTDxf)dxf.copy();
>       stylesTable.putDxf(dxfNew);
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code. I verified with .xlsx and I believe it would work with .xls also.

```
            int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
            CellStyle newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();   
            newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle()); 
            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
            styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);

            if ( (newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() instanceof XSSFWorkbook) && (oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() instanceof XSSFWorkbook) ){
                StylesTable newStylesSource = ((XSSFWorkbook) newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()).getStylesSource();
                StylesTable oldStylesSource = ((XSSFWorkbook) oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()).getStylesSource();
                for (XSSFCellFill fill : oldStylesSource.getFills()) {
                    XSSFCellFill fillNew = new XSSFCellFill(fill.getCTFill());
                    newStylesSource.putFill(fillNew);
                }
                for (XSSFCellBorder border : oldStylesSource.getBorders()) {
                    XSSFCellBorder borderNew = new XSSFCellBorder(border.getCTBorder());
                    newStylesSource.putBorder(borderNew);
                }
            }
```